# Rerun Failed Behat Tests Only A Set Number of Times

Tags: behat

I have an Behat testing suite running through Travis CI on Pull Requests. I know that you can add a "--rerun" option to the command line to rerun failed tests, but for me Behat just keeps trying to rerun the failed tests, which eventually times out the test run session.

Is there a way to limit the number of times that failed tests are re-ran? Something like: "behat --rerun=3" for trying to run a failed scenario up to three times?

The only other way I can think to accomplish what I want is to use the database I'm testing Behat against or to write to a file and store test failures and the number of times they have been run.

EDIT:

Locally, running the following command ends up re-running only the one test I purposely made to fail...and it does it in a loop until something happens. Sometimes it was 11 times and sometimes 100+ times.

```
behat --tags @some_tag
behat --rerun
```

So, that doesn't match what the [behat command line guide](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/6.cli.html) states. In my terminal, the help option give me "--rerun Re-run scenarios that failed during last execution." without any mention of the failed scenario file. I'm using a 3.0 version of behat though.

Packages used:

```
    "behat/behat": "~3.0",
    "behat/mink": "~1.5",
    "behat/mink-extension": "~2.0",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "~1.0",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "~1.1",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "~1.1",
    "drupal/drupal-extension": "~3.0"
```

Problem:

Test fail at random due to mainly Guzzle timeout errors going past 30 seconds trying to GET a URL. Sure you could try bumping up the max execution time, but since other tests have no issues and 30 seconds is a long time to wait for a request, I don't think that will fix the issue and it will make my test runs much longer for not a good reason.

Comment: In the link you provided there is some info that you can pass a filename to rerun option to save the failed scenarios, or some existing file is used. is possible that might be a bug with rerun.I will give it a try tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you might not have an efficient CI setup?

I think that this option should run the failed tests only once and maybe your setup enters in a loop.
If you need to run the failed scenarios for a number of times maybe you should write a script that checks some condition and runs with --rerun.

Be aware that as i see on the Behat CLI guide if no scenario was found in the file where the failed scenarios are saved then all scenarios will be executed.

I don't think that using '--rerun' in CI is good practice. You should do a high level review of the results before deciding to do a rerun.

I checked today the rerun on Behat 3 and it seems there might be a bug related to the rerun option, i saw today some pull requests on github.
One of them is https://github.com/Behat/Behat/pull/857

Related to the timeout you can check if Travis has some timeout to set, it it has enough resources and you can use the same steps to run it from desktop and see the difference for the same test environment.

Also set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT for guzzle with the value needed to pass in case is not to exaggerated and you will need to find other solution to improve the execution speed.

It should not be such an issue to have a higher value because this should be a conditional wait, so if is faster it will not impact the execution time, else it will wait longer for problematic scenarios.

Comment: So how do you handle random timeouts or max execution errors? I know of using a "spin" function, but when I've seen that used the code is looking for a specific element to show up on the page. When I run the tests locally or isolated or in a different order I get no errors. I'll try to play around with the rerun file.

Comment: Depending of the type of timeout? If the element is not found then you can implement a general method to be used for finding an element, if the page is not loaded you can add a method to wait for the page to be loaded, if you have some other type of request that you need to wait to be completed you can add a wait method for that. Where the scenarios are executed? Do you use a VM or a 'selenium as a service' like Sauce Labs or BrowserStack? If you can give more details then please update your question.

Comment: I updated my question. The problem is that there is no element to look for, and the timeout isn't specific to any one scenario. I don't want to look for a generic element that is on every page, plus the waitForElement method wouldn't work since there would be no page to check for an element, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, i had too little info. Have you tried to increase the timeout to more than 30 seconds just for test? If you execute on the same environment the same scenarios from local and with CI and from CI you have some fails is a good chance that the issues are from Travis CI.